# c# swagger openapi erronous refs when nested classes

Tags: c#, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Default swagger generation for my API gives me errors when uploading my OpenAPI to Azure API Management. Testing with Swagger Editor, it specifies the follwoing error:

"$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs".

It seems my data types with nested classes is transformed to:

```
$ref: >-
              #/components/schemas/Namespace.Class+NestedClass
```

I guess it is the '+'-sign that either needs to be removed or encoded.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: What error does Azure give you? While it's true that OAS3 does not allow `+` in schema names, there might be other problems related to [Azure's OAS import limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions#-openapiswagger-import-limitations). Also, what tool do you use to generate the API definition - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: Azure error: Parsing error(s): The key 'Namespace.Class+NestedClass' in 'schemas' of components MUST match the regular expression '^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+$'. [#/components]. Swagger Editor error: Semantic error at components.schemas.Namepsace.Class.properties.NestesClass.items.$ref
$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs. The API definition is generated by Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.

Comment: This is a Swashbuckle issue, it generates schema names with unsupported characters (in this case - `+`). Open an issue at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue when trying to publish a service with api management.

> Parsing error(s): The key 'Namespace.Class+NestedClass' in 'schemas' of components MUST match the regular expression '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+$'. [#/components]

In my case using custom schema ids and replacing the character that causes the error solved the problem:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName.Replace("+", "_"));
});
```